# How to tell current frequency band?

Tags: networking, samsung-galaxy-ace, gsm

I have a Samsung Galaxy Ace, with quad-band I believe. It is possible to see the current connection network type, e.g. UMTS, EDGE, etc, by going to Settings -> About Phone -> Status. But it does not tell which frequency band it is on. Is it possible to find out which frequency band (either exactly, or just which of the four major bands) that I am using?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Based on avirk's hint, I found a way. First press the code *#0011#

**GSM example:**

```
GSM900: IDLE
T: 10, B: 10
Rx Pwr: -94, Rx ual: -
Rx Lev: 21, Tx Lev: 0-
Speech VER: AMR EFR FR
VOC: AdaptiveRate
TS: 0
Temp: 68 Batt: 71 LNA: 0
Service: Available
```

It is obvious that it's using 900MHz band, from the "GSM900".

**UMTS WCDMA example:**

```
WCDMA: Idle
Rx CH: 10612, R: -94
Tx CH: 9662, Tx Pwr: -
EdIo: -6, RSCP: -98
SpeechVER: AMR EFR FR
RF: Sleep2
L1: PCH_Sleep
Drx cycle: 64, PSC: 392
Temp: 67 Batt: 69 LNA: 0
Service: Available
```

UMTS can use two different physical layers (low level radio) UMTS-FDD and UMTS-TDD. Android just shows WCDMA, which I think is the same as UMTS-FDD, but perhaps it can refer to both of them. By looking up the channel number [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UMTS_frequency_bands#UMTS-FDD) you can tell the frequency bands and whether it is UMTS-FDD or UMTS-TDD.

In the above example it is using UMTS-FDD, the down-link channel (Rx) is in the 2100MHz band and the up-link channel (Tx) is in the 1900MHz band.

Comment: Is the code carrier or country related, because here it just says "Connection problem or invalid MMI code."

Answer (score 11):

You can try dialing

```
*#*#4636#*#*
```

and then going to "Phone Information".

[image]

That will show details about the network like cell tower ID and network type.
As you can see from the below screenshot, it shows "EDGE" mode :-

[image]

Also, this may only work on stock Android builds.

Comment: Not working on my Galaxy S..

Comment: BTW, there's no info about frequency band even there...

Comment: Edited and made corrections to the code.. try it now, @SachinShekhar ; afaik, It works on all ROMs

Comment: Can you tell me why you have posted this just to show EDGE network? It can be found directly in `Settings` ~> `About Phone` ~> `Status`... He is asking for Frequency Band, not Network type.

Comment: Thanks. It still does not tell me which frequency band. For instance I believe that some phones can work with GSM on both 900MHz and 1800MHz bands.

Comment: Oh yes, I know, atleast it does answer a part of your question, and anyways, @SachinShekhar, this wasn't posted by me originally. ;)

Comment: my case, it says, LTE unknown...

Comment: I could get frequency information by setting the "Cell Info Refresh Rate" spinner

Answer (score 3):

[LTE Discovery](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.simplyadvanced.ltediscovery) app tells this for 4G/LTE.

[image: IMG:]

Comment: It requires rooting…

Comment: My phone isn't rooted.

Comment: It doesn't require rooting for this function

Comment: In some cases, this app only tells you the LTE channel number, via "Signals → Show Advanced Data → Service State → Channel Number". You can then use [this tool](https://5g-tools.com/4g-lte-earfcn-calculator/) to calculate which LTE band this channel belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [MTK engineering tool](http://www.techsng.com/2016/10/check-4g-network-bands-android.html)? It works pretty well for most android phones i've come across as it also shows you the current 4G bands.